# Question about exercise 11.3 in TeXbook

Tags: tex-core

The answer says

> You probably predicted a height of **8.9861**

I wonder which calculations should be made to predict such a height. The most simple calculations produce the value 8.98608, namely:

Take the old height (6.83331) and add to it the amount of shift (2.15277), which yields `6.83331+2.15277=`**8.98608**

Comment: My TeXbook doesn't even have that comment (commenting on the width instead). Moreover, the "old height" is 6.83333.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau My copy has the comments as Igor's

Comment: I agree the comment doesn't really make sense: there's no reason to work in `pt` here as we _know_ the sizes the information earlier in the chapter

Comment: Possibly a mix-up due to the shift from AM to CM fonts.

Comment: I would guess that there was some mix-up with old and new numbers at the time the fonts were changed (@egreg), and Don noticed (1) the discrepancy in width was gone, and (2) the new height didn't match the height calculated from the *old original* log listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations. I think you've found an error in *The TeXbook*. However, apparently according to [https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/abcde.html](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/abcde.html) there are printings that include changes not included in the errata files on ctan and it's unclear that the `texbook.tex` source on ctan (which includes this error) is the same as the latest printing.